# why get function call multiple times in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-directive

I make a simple demo `user login` screen .I am facing one issue that `get property` function call multiple times (`4 times`).

Step to reproduce

1. Enter `10 digit number or email` example `test@gmail.com`
2. Click `continue button` it show `password` screen.
3. click on `change email or mobile no` and see the console log it call `four (4) times`

here is my code

[image]

is there my implementation is wrong ?

here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p5knn6?file=src%2Fapp%2Flogin-component%2Flogin-component.component.html

```
get userenterValue() {
    console.log('log==')
    return this.userInfo.username;
  }

  set userenterValue(val) {
    this.userInfo.username = val;
  }
```

Comment: nothing in the code you posted here would cause console.log to be executed 4 times. In fact, what you have posted wouldn't get executed at all

Answer (score 1):

That is expected, since you are using **`ngModel`** with set , whenever there is a change input value there will be a console.log entry.

The value bound on the html has to be evaluated every time something "has changed" in the app so that if the value of the bound item has changed it will be reflected to the html

Instead you could use ngBlur to get the value when the focus is left.

Comment: The `console.log` is printing 4 times even before anything is typed & if that is the case there is not specific reason that it will print only 4 times, it can be more or less also

Comment: That is what, since you are using getters https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Comment: Sorry i should have stated whenever there is a change instead of whenever you change. Now answer is updated

Comment: @Sajeetharan I think you didnot understand my Question

Comment: i understood your question and thats the reason as well

Comment: @Sajeetharan please `click on change email or mobile` button .and check the console..Please follow the steps

Comment: @Sajeetharan when I clicked `changes email` I changed `value` at `once` it only call `one` time why `four`

Comment: is there any better way to implement same functionality

Comment: you do not need getter and setter, use change ngBlur

Comment: can you change my HTML or share `stackblitz` url

Comment: you want to get the value on click continue?

Comment: yes I want .. please put that value in `userinfo` object

Comment: when User click on `change email or mobile` it `email` id become empty

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding it using getters and setters. How about you try binding with the property itself like:

```
<input type="text" name="email"
       autocomplete="off"
       placeholder="Enter the Email or Number"
       [(ngModel)]="userInfo.username"
       required
       [disabled]="showPasswordField"
       pattern="^(\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+)$|^(\d{10})$">
```